# How to make a synchronous API call which is nested inside another API failure callback in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

In getRatingReviewFromServer(), if I get success everything is fine, but if I get failed I need to call another API refreshToken() if I get success on refreshToken() call I will call getRatingReviewFromServer() again with new data I will be getting from refreshToken() success.
How can I achieve this goal with the best approach?

```
    func getData(){
        service.getRatingReviewFromServer(succeed: {(message) in
                // my code code
                //exits
            }, failure: {message in
                service.refreshToken(succeed: {
                    data in
                    // call RatingReviewService().getRatingReviewFromServer() again
                }, failure: {
                    msg in
                    //exits
                })
         })
     }
```

How can i do something like this?

Comment: Use the closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func getData() {
    service.getRatingReviewFromServer(succeed: { (message) in
        // my code code
        //exits
     }, failure: { [weak self] (message) in
         service.refreshToken(succeed: { [weak self] (data) in
             // call RatingReviewService().getRatingReviewFromServer() again
            
             // You can restart the call
             self?.getData()
             
         }, failure: {
             msg in
             //exits
         })
     })
}
```

Comment: Make sure that you limit the maximum number of calls because if you don't, this code can create an infinite loop in case of an issue on the server side.

Comment: Yes i have a flag for that.